# How to write multiple middlewares in single js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I am new to `loopback`, I have written 2 middlewares in a single file named it as `myMiddilwares.js`. I want to configure these middlewares on different rest API's in `middileware.json` . This is how it looks like

```
myMiddilwares.js

 function first(req,res,next) {
    console.log("This is first middileware");
    next();
 }

function second(req,res,next) {
   console.log("This is second middileware");
   next();
}

module.exports=function(){
   return {
     first:first,
     second:second
   }
}
```

This is how, I have tried to configure in `middileware.json`, but it's not working

```
 "routes": {
    "./middleware/myMiddilwares#first": {
       "paths": ["/first"]
    },
    "./middleware/myMiddilwares#second": {
       "paths": ["/second"]
    }
}
```

can anyone help me thanks

Comment: I think that you actually have to return the middleware function, so try `function first() { return (req, res, next) => ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
    module.exports={

         first:function(req,res,next) {
              console.log("This is first middileware");
              next();
             }



         second:function(req,res,next) {
               console.log("This is second middileware");
                next();
             }

    }
```

Comment: your approach not working, it expecting middleware funtion. So we suppose to return middleware function as @Explosion Pillas suggested.